# May I run only half of a neural network model when doing prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am trying to use the Deep-Semantic-Similarity-Model to calculate query and document similarity in document search. I want to compute all the documents' embedding vectors offline/beforehand, to accomplish that means after training, I have to run only half of the model to predict/calculate the documents' embedding vectors. But I don't know how to do that? Is it possible in `keras` or `tensorflow`?
e.g. using [this](https://github.com/airalcorn2/Deep-Semantic-Similarity-Model) project

Comment: Yes, you may! By using `tf.cond()` with boolean placeholder as a predicate. Show us what have you tried so far so we could help you.

Comment: @Vlad, I am using keras now, the code is like this:
model = Model(inputs = [query, pos_doc] + neg_docs, outputs = prob)
model.compile(optimizer = "adadelta", loss = "categorical_crossentropy")
the input to model is a pair of query and positive-document and a few negative documents, as in the file https://github.com/airalcorn2/Deep-Semantic-Similarity-Model/blob/master/deep_semantic_similarity_keras.py. How can I use the model to calculate only document embedding?

Comment: To implement this you need to use *tensorflow* low level API. I don't think you can do it using keras only.

Comment: @Vlad, Thank you! I will try it.